# Are there arbitrarily large families of lines in $\Bbb R^3$ with average angle $\ge \pi/3$?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, measure-theory, discrete-geometry, expectation

> **Question:** Can I have an arbitrarily large finite family of lines $\ell_1,\dotsc,\ell_n\subset\Bbb R^3$ so that the average angle between two (distinct) lines is $\ge \pi/3$?

We can assume that all lines pass through the origin, and by angle I mean the smaller one of the two angles defined by two intersecting lines.

If my integral calculus hasn't failed me, then the expected angle between two random lines with uniformly chosen directions is exactly $1\, \mathrm{rad}$, wheras $\pi/3\approx 1.0472 >1$.
So generic arrangements won't do it. Can I be more clever? Or is there perhaps some standard measure theory argument that tells me that in the limit, uniformly chosen lines is the best I can do? If so, can we put a bound on $n$ for where this stops being possible?

I know from random experiments that $n=17$ is possible, but already for $n=18$ I have no examples so far.

---

**Update**

The [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428555/are-there-arbitrarily-large-families-of-lines-in-bbb-r3-with-average-angle#comment1102298_428555) by alesia answers the question as posed (and I am looking forward to accept their [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/428607)): there are arbitrarily large families of lines with average angle $> \pi/3$.
Though one should note that the bound $\pi/3$ still seems kind of substantial: the more lines I have, the close the average will be to $\pi/3$.
I won't change the question (I might post a separate one), but the following seems to be the more fundamental question:

> Is there a probability distribution on lines in $\Bbb R^3$ so that the expected value for the angle between two (independently sampled) lines is $>\pi/3$?

I think *No* and I am looking forward to ideas. The value $\pi/3$ is attained by alesia's construction (uniformly
choosing directions from an orthogonal basis).

Comment: Nice problem.  But you are asking in the wrong forum.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Can you elaborate? I don't see that this would be better at Math.SE. If you consider this elementary, then can you point me to the right tools?

Comment: if you have an example with average x, you can just replace each line with n lines that are epsilon away from it and you get an example with n times more lines and average at least x - 2*epsilon.

Comment: @alesia I am not sure that this is true. Even if $\epsilon\to 0$, the average will be pulled down by the many almost parallel lines and will end up smaller than $x$. Am I missing something?

Comment: ah, you are taking average over distinct pairs of lines. Then yes, this trick doesn't work

Comment: This seems perfectly reasonable for MO to me. The problem comes down to some sort of inequality for the first and second moment of a random variable on the unit sphere, and I haven't worked out what the inequality is yet, but I just wanted to record that the question seems fine.

Comment: wait, if you take as first arrangement four lines whose directions point to the vertices of a regular tetrahedron and then use the trick above, don't you get 3/4*109 > 60 degrees?

Comment: @alesia Since you write $109^\circ$, I suspect that you measured the wrong (i.e. the large) angle between two lines. Could this be? I arrive at $\approx 3/4 \times 70^\circ<60^\circ$.

Comment: yes you're right

Comment: Why do you ask specifically for the average angle being at least $\pi/3$, rather than some other value?

Comment: you can get arbitrarily close to pi/3 by "blurring" a distribution concentrated on 3 orthogonal lines

Comment: @VarunVejalla This came out of my specific application. If some other bound can be achieved, even if worse, this would still be interesting.

Comment: Last attempt : consider the union of n triples of orthogonal lines obtained by rotating one triple by random rotations with small enough angles.

Comment: @alesia That's an interesting observation indeed (also the same as replacing each of the three lines by $N$ closeby lines, right?). So the limit $\pi/3$ seems not so arbitrary after all. To your second comment: this also approaches $60^\circ$, am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: It's a particular instance of the first idea yes. It should be arbitrarily close to 60 degrees yes, perhaps it can get lower but i'm not sure. It might depend on the exact distribution on the the small rotations

Comment: The question appears to be equivalent to asking whether the self-adjoint integral operator $I f(\theta) := \int_{S^2} |\angle(\theta,\alpha)| f(\alpha)\ d\alpha$ fails to be negative semi-definite on the space $L^2(S^2)_0$ of square-integrable mean zero functions on the sphere.  This should be decidable by testing this operator on spherical harmonics and using some classical identities, but I unfortunately don't have time to work out the details.

Comment: Not for the same exact problem, but [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1306.0256.pdf) might be helpful.

Comment: Alesia is right.  Divide $n$ into three parts (as closely as you can).  Lines from one part are parallel to the $x$-axis.  Lines form the second part to the $y$-axis.  Lines from the third part to the $z$-axis.  Some pairs of lines have angle $0$, other pairs have angle $\pi/2$.  Compute the average angle.  It is greater than $\pi/3$.  When $n \to \infty$, the average angle converges to $\pi/3$.

Comment: @TerryTao I wish you had the time to spell out what you are thinking, because I don't see it (and also don't see how to make my suggestion work). Alesia's distribution (with the weight concentrated on three orthogonal points) beats the uniform distribution, whereas it seems to me that your approach could only work to show that the uniform distribution was optimal.

Comment: Wouldn’t the average angle between two randomly chosen vectors on the unit sphere be $\pi/2$, not $1$?

Comment: @VarunVejalla  I think the problem is that the average angle between two lines is not the same as between two vectors.

Comment: Are we talking about lines through the origin? (if not, I'm not sure how we're defining the angle between two skew lines.)

Comment: By zooming out we are essentially talking about lines through the origin (as opposed to half lines/vectors) and the angle among two of them therefore ranges between $0$ and $\pi/2$.

Comment: @alesia Your idea (with some detail added) works and you should write it is as an answer: 1) take the three orthogonal lines you mentioned, 2) allow multiplicities and replace each line with $n$ copies of itself, now the average is angle is $\frac{3n^2\times \pi/2+3n(n-1)/2\times 0}{3n^2+3n(n-1)/2}>\frac{3n^2\times \pi/2+3n^2/2\times 0}{3n^2+3n^2/2}=\pi/3$, 3) last wiggle the overlapping lines a small enough amount so that they become all different while the average angle remains $>\pi/3$.

Comment: For your new question, do you mean the angle between two independent lines sampled from the distribution? Also the question formulated in terms of the distribution is equivalent to a combinatorial one: does there exists $\alpha>\pi/3$ and line configurations with arbitrarily many lines such that the average angle is at least $\alpha$? Basically, from a given distribution you can find configurations with as many lines and as close an average angle as you want, and from a configuration of $n$ lines  with average angle $\alpha$ the empirical distribution has average angle $(1-1/n)\alpha$.

Comment: Just to add one more comment (sorry, no solution!) there are many other probability distributions that yield $\pi/3$. One choice is to take our line to pass through the poles with probability $1/3$ and to pass through a point chosen uniformly on the equator  with probability $2/3$. More generally, we can use any probability distribution on the equator which is symmetric under a rotation of $\pi/2$.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch oh you're right, since the two lines have to be distinct, the probability to get two lines in the same cluster is slightly less, making the average > pi/3

Comment: Name of @VarunVejalla's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428555/are-there-arbitrarily-large-families-of-lines-in-bbb-r3-with-average-angle#comment1102306_428555):  [Cai, Fan, and Jiang - Distributions of Angles in Random Packing on Spheres](https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.0256).

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Ah, I see what you are saying now; I had misread the original post as claiming that the uniform distribution was optimal. I withdraw my remark.

Comment: For the first (and already answered) question, I was able to compute examples for $n\leq 133$ by starting with $n$ electrons on the projective plane (this projective plane has resistance to absorb energy) and then letting those electrons move to the location that minimizes the electrical potential energy (the particles are repelled from each other with a constant force, so we need to modify Coulomb's law). This sometimes works, but I often have to start the computation over again if the potential energy reaches a large local minimum.

Comment: If we use *ordered* pairs of not necessarily distinct lines (so $n^2$ pairs for $n$ lines), 1) is there any example with average angle $>\pi/3$ and 2) is $\pi/3$ only attained by equal numbers of lines in each of 3 orthogonal directions? A (likely) negative answer to 1) would also imply a negative answer to the question about distributions.

Comment: Ah, David Speyer already answered my second question in the negative (eg. 2 identical lines through the poles and 4 equally spaced on the equator)!

Comment: Your conjecture in the update seems to be a known open problem. See the references and improved upper bound in this answer: 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/173712/maximum-sum-of-angles-between-n-lines/283104#283104

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Start with $n$ times each coordinate axis, so $3n$ lines in total. The average angle between non necessarily distinct lines is $1/3*0 + 2/3*\pi/2 = \pi/3$. So the average angle between "distinct" lines (here, distinct lines may coincide geometrically due to multiplicities) is greater than $\pi/3$.

You can then perturb the lines to make them geometrically distinct while keeping an average angle larger than $\pi/3$.

Although that's not the question, I'm not sure what happens if one wants an infinite number of lines.

Answer (score 7):

$\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}$I have been working on and off on the problem where we sample ordered pairs $(x,y)$ of lines, with duplicates allowed. To make sure the problem is clearly understood, I'll restate it: For $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ two lines through the origin in $\RR^3$, define $d(\ell_1, \ell_2)$ to be the acute angle that they make. In other words, if $v_1$ and $v_2$ are unit vectors on $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$, then $d(\ell_1, \ell_2)$ is $\cos^{-1} |v_1 \cdot v_2|$.

The problem now is that we have $n$ lines $\ell_1$, $\ell_2$, ..., $\ell_n$. We sample two lines $\ell_i$ and $\ell_j$ independently at random from these $n$. The problem is to show that the expected value of $d(\ell_i, \ell_j)$ is at most $\pi/3$. As has been observed many times, equality occurs when we have three mutually orthogonal lines: $\tfrac{3}{9} \cdot 0 + \tfrac{6}{9} \cdot \tfrac{\pi}{2} = \tfrac{\pi}{3}$. If we can handle the discrete case, we can also handle more general probability distributions, but I find the discrete case easier to think about.

Here are the results I have gotten:

**Proposition 1** For $n \geq 3$, in any local maximum, any line in the configuration is perpendicular to at least two other lines in the configuration.

**Proposition 2** The result is true for $n \leq 4$ lines.

**Proposition 3** The result is true for families of $3n$ lines $(u_1, v_1, w_1, u_2, v_2, w_2, \ldots, u_n, v_n, w_n)$ where each $(u_i, v_i, w_i)$ is orthogonal.

It looks like it might be true that Proposition 1 could be strengthened to

**Conjecture 4** For $n \geq 3$, any local maximum contains three orthogonal lines.

**Proposition 5** If we can show Conjecture 4, the result follows.

---

Here are the proofs. We first need:

**Lemma 6** Consider $d(x,y)$ as a function of $x \in S^2$, with $y$ fixed. Away from $\pm y$ and $y^{\perp}$, this is a smooth function and its Hessian (using the standard Riemannian metric on $S^2$) is positive semidefinite.

**Proof** Normalize $y$ to be the north pole and use polar coordinates $(\theta, \phi)$ for $x$, so $d(x,y) = \min(\phi, \pi - \phi)$. This is clearly smooth away from the equator $\phi = \pi/2$ and from the poles (where spherical coordinates aren't defined). I'll work in the northern hemisphere, where $\phi < \pi/2$, so $d(x,y) = \phi$.

Thanks to  user3658307, I know the formula for the [spherical Hessian](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2377837/448). All the second derivatives vanish, as does the derivative with respect to $\theta$, and the Hessian is just
$$\begin{bmatrix} \cos \phi \sin \phi \tfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial \phi} &0 \\ 0&0 \end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix} \cos \phi \sin \phi & 0 \\ 0&0 \\ \end{bmatrix}.$$
Since $0 < \phi < \pi/2$, we have $\cos \phi \sin \phi>0$ and this is positive semidefinite. $\square$

**Corollary 7** Let $x_1$, $x_2$, ..., $x_n$ be points on $S^2$. Suppose that $x_n$ is not orthogonal to and of the $x_i$ or equal to $\pm x_i$. Then the Hessian of $\sum_{i,j} d(x_i, x_j)$ with respect to $x_n$ is positive semidefinite.

**Proof** The sum of positive semidefinite matrices is positive semidefinite. $\square$

**Proof sketch for Proposition 1** Using Corollary 7 and the second derivative test on Riemannian manifolds, we see that a local maximum cannot have any point $x_n$ as in the hypotheses of Corollary 7. Furthermore, taking some of the $x_i$ equal to $\pm x_n$ only makes things worse, since $d(x, y)$ is convex up for $x$ near $\pm y$. (I don't know the right language to say "convex up" for a non-smooth function on a Riemannian manifold, but I'm pretty confident that I'm right.) Even taking $x_n$ orthogonal to one $x_i$ doesn't help, since we could then wiggle $x_n$ along $x_i^{\perp}$ and $\sum_{j \neq i,n} d(x_j, x_n)$ will be convex up there by the Corollary. So, in any local maximum, each $x_n$ must be orthogonal to at least two distinct $x_i$. $\square$

**Proof of Proposition 2:** For $n \leq 3$ lines, the result is clear.
So we turn to the case of $4$ lines. Let $\Gamma$ be the graph with vertices $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$ and an edge $(i,j)$ if $\ell_i \perp \ell_j$. Then Proposition 1 says that every vertex of $\Gamma$ has degree $\geq 2$. Every such graph on $4$ vertices contains a $4$-cycle; assume WLOG that $\ell_1 \perp \ell_2$, $\ell_2 \perp \ell_3$, $\ell_3 \perp \ell_4$ and $\ell_4 \perp \ell_1$.

Then $\text{Span}(\ell_1, \ell_3) \perp \text{Span}(\ell_2, \ell_4)$. Since we are in $3$-dimensional space, one of these two spaces must be one-dimensional, so either $\ell_1 = \ell_3$ or $\ell_2 = \ell_4$, WLOG $\ell_2  = \ell_4$. Then either Prop 3 applied to $\ell_3$, or a direct computation, shows that the optimal choice is $\ell_1 \perp \ell_3$. $\square$

**Lemma 8** Let $\ell_1$, $\ell_2$, $\ell_3$ be orthogonal and let $\ell$ be any other line. Then $\sum_{i=1}^3 d(\ell_i, \ell) \leq \pi$.

**Proof** This either follows directly from Prop 1 or from Prop 2. $\square$.

**Proof of Prop 3** We break up our expected value into terms where both lines are chosen from the same triple $(u_i, v_i, w_i)$, and terms where the lines come from distinct triples.

When both lines come from the same triple, the expected value is $(3/9)(0)+(6/9)(\pi/2) = \pi/3$.

For two different triples $(u_i, v_i, w_i)$ and $(u_j, v_j, w_j)$, we have $9$ summands. Break them into three sums of $3$ summands each, and bound each of them above by Lemma 8. $\square$.

I note that every equality case that we know is of the form in Proposition 3 (which is why I started considering it).

Finally, I'll **prove Proposition 5**: Our proof is by induction on $n$, with the base cases $n \leq 2$ clear. If $n \geq 3$, let $(\ell_1, \ell_2, \ell_3)$ be mutually orthogonal. Then break our expected value of $d(\ell_i, \ell_j)$ into four sums, depending on whether $i$ and $j$ are $\leq 3$ or $\geq 4$.

If both are $\leq 3$, the expected value is $\pi/3$.

If $i\leq 3$ and $j \geq 4$, fix $j$ and bound the sum on $i$ by Lemma 8. If $i \geq 4$ and $j \leq 3$, do the same thing with the roles of $i$ and $j$ fixed.

Finally, if $i$, $j \geq 4$, we have the result by induction. $\square$

Some more thoughts: Define $\Gamma$ as in the proof of Prop 2. If $\Gamma$ has a triangle, then we can split it off as in the proof of Prop 5 and induct. If $\Gamma$ has a $4$-cycle, then we can use the $\text{Span}(\ell_1, \ell_3) \perp \text{Span}(\ell_2, \ell_4)$ trick in the proof of Prop 2, although I'm not actually sure how we finish the argument from there.

If we can partition the vertices of $\Gamma$ into two classes $I$ and $J$ with $\leq 2$ edges between vertices of different classes, then I think I have one more trick: Apply a rotation matrix $g \in SO(3)$ to $\ell_j$ for $j \in J$ while fixing $\ell_i$ for $i \in I$; since $SO(3)$ is $3$-dimensional and there are only two summands which are convex down, I think you can use a computation like the proof of Prop 1 to show that this cannot be a local maximum. But I am not good enough at Riemannian geometry to be confident in this.

The first graph I know for which none of these tricks apply (i.e. all vertices degree $\geq 2$, no triangles or quadrilaterals, and $3$-edge connected) is the [Petersen graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Petersen_Graph).

Comment: I didn't completely follow your conditional proof of Proposition 5, so I may just be repeating your argument: one can prove that the average angle between a line and a triplet (of mutually orthogonal lines) is always $\le \pi/3$. Therefore if the average of the $n^2$ angles of a set is $> \pi/3$ then so is the average of the $(n-3)^2$ angles after removing the orthogonal triplet.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch Yes, this is what I was saying.

Comment: Taking a clue from **Proposition 1**, I looked at $\ell_1\perp\ell_2\perp\ell_3\perp\ell_4\perp\ell_5\perp\ell_1$ where the 5 lines go through the origin and each of the 5 points $(-1,0,0)$, $(0,-1,0)$, $(\cos(\alpha), 0, \sin(\alpha)), (-\sin(\alpha), -\sin(\alpha), \cos(\alpha))/\sqrt{1+\sin(\alpha)^2}$ and $(0,\cos(\alpha), \sin(\alpha))$. The average angle is then $8\pi/25$ at both $\alpha=0$ and $\alpha=\pi/2$, and very slightly **lower** than that in between. Too bad. Perhaps  I'll try something similar for 6 lines.

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment and *please check my arguments*. I think that there may be gaps there. This is however in the spirit of @DavidESpeyer's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428555/are-there-arbitrarily-large-families-of-lines-in-bbb-r3-with-average-angle#comment1102285_428555):

Given the Gram matrix formed by the inner products of $M$ (real or complex valued) vectors of dimension $n,$
$$
G=[\langle x_i,x_j\rangle]_{M\times M}
$$
the Welch bound (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch_bounds)) can be written as
$$
\sum_{1\leq i,j\leq M} \lvert\langle x_i,x_j\rangle\rvert^2 \geq \frac{\mathbb{tr}(G)^2}{n}
$$
which becomes
$$
\sum_{i} \langle x_i,x_i \rangle^2+
\sum_{i\neq j} \lvert\langle x_i, x_j \rangle\rvert^2 \geq
\frac{(\sum_{i} \langle x_i, x_i \rangle)^2}{n}.
$$
Keep in mind that we can consider unit nonzero vectors, and that a vector and its opposite represent the same line. Continuing:
$$
M(1)^2+\sum_{i\neq j} \lvert\langle x_i, x_j \rangle\rvert^2 \geq
\frac{M^2}{n},
$$
or
$$
\sum_{i\neq j} \lvert\langle x_i, x_j \rangle\rvert^2 \geq
\frac{M(M-1)}{n},
$$
which when divided by the number of pairs of vectors ($M(M-1)$) gives
$$
\mathbb{E}\{\lvert\langle x_i,x_j\rangle\rvert^2\}
\geq \frac{M(M-1)}{M(M-1)}=\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{3},
$$
since we have $n=3$, being in 3 dimensional real space.
This gives
$$
\cos^2(\theta)\geq \frac{1}{3}
$$
for the minimal angle, or $\theta\geq 54.735\cdots$ degrees somewhat under one radian.

**Now, since all these angles are equal, it would seem that a perturbation of one line in this arrangement would actually *increase* the average angle.** Assuming this, argument above is independent of $M$ it hasn't managed to rule out an arbitrarily large set of lines with this value. But for all angles below this value, it seems that one cannot have an equal angle arrangement.

Independently, I just found out (wikipedia again) that there are upper bounds to the maximum number of *equiangular lines* of $\binom{n+1}{2}$ in $n$-dimensional Euclidean space, which gives 6 lines for this case but 12 if we also take the opposite of each line. This might mean that if the perturbation argument above can be made rigorous then the vectors pointing to the centres of the 12 faces of a regular icosahedron may be the best possible for the angle corresponding to those vectors.

Comment: The part where you prove the expected value of $\cos^2(\theta)$ is at least $1/3$ is correct and seems potentially useful, but I don't see how to finish from there. Suppose we could find a limit of line arrangements where $\cos^2(\theta)$ was equal to $y$ with probability $1/(3y)$ and was equal to $0$ with probability $(3y-1)/(3y)$. Then the expected value of $\cos^2(\theta)$ is still $1/3$, and the expected value of $\theta$ is $\tfrac{1}{3y} \tfrac{\cos^{-1} (2y-1)}{2} + \tfrac{3y-1}{3y} \tfrac{\pi}{2}$. I get that this is maximized at $y \approx 0.837$, with value $1.11 > \pi/3$.

Comment: An idea: Let $t(x)$ be $x$ for $0 \leq x \leq \pi/2$, $\pi-x$ for $\pi/2 \leq x \leq \pi$ and periodic modulo $\pi$. We want to upper bound the expected value of $t(\theta)$. I believe that the Fourier series of $t(\theta)$ looks like $a_0 - \sum a_{2m+1} \cos((4m+2) \theta) = (a_0 + \sum a_{2m+1}) - 2 \sum_n a_{2m+1} \cos^2((2m+1) \theta)$ for some *positive* $a_{2m+1}$. Is there any way we could adapt this answer to show that the expected value of $\cos^2((2m+1) \theta)$ is always $\geq 1/3$ (which is the value for alesia's arrangement?). Then we would get the desired bound.

Comment: I added a link to a comment of @DavidESpeyer that seemed to be, and hopefully is, the one that you meant.  If I got it wrong, then please feel free to correct.

Comment: I believe I can show that, if $P_n(x)$ is a Legendre polynomial, then the expected value of $P_n(\cos \theta)$ is $\geq 0$. Since $P_2(x) = (3/2) x^2-1/2$, this generalizes the result that $E(\cos^2 \theta) \geq 1/3$. I can't find a way to use this, but if anyone else can, let me know and I'll write up the proof.

Comment: In particular, the expansion for the triangular wave $t(\theta)$ in $P_n(\cos \theta)$ starts $t(\theta) = 1 - (5/6) P_2(\cos \theta) + (3/40) P_4(\cos \theta) - \cdots$. So the coefficients do not have uniform sign.